# Firebase.setAndroidContext while working with an Activity and multiple Services

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, android-context

I'm using Firebase from my main `Activity` and from a couple of `Services`.

How and when should I call `Firebase.setAndroidContext(Context)`?

In their documentation, Firebase suggests to call it in my `Activity.OnCreate()` (See [Setup Firebase on Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/setup.html)).

However, how will that affect the `Services`? And should I set it also for them? As they may run before the `Activity`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase documentation you refer to says:

> If your Android app has multiple activities, add this code to your [Application Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). Otherwise add it in your main activity.

If you have services, put it in the [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

Comment: I'm encountering similar issues Mugen laid out in his question above since we're developing an SDK instead of an application. What should be done in that case?